# Clone/duplicate object around circular path in Animate cc

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-animate

In Adobe Animate cc, I have a circle with stroke and no fill. I want to place copy of symbol on the circumference of the circle at equal distance. Ctrl + D duplicate the symbol, but it paste in diagonal path. I want it to paste in circular path. I'm looking similar to rotate tool in Illustrator where we can rotate and follow Ctrl + D to paste in circular path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this in Animate CC.  The first way is by adjusting the origin of the symbol, which I prefer.

First, align your circle and your symbol.
[image]

Then double click on the symbol to enter isolation mode and move it to the desired position relative to the circle.

[image]

Double click the empty stage to return, then copy and Paste In Place (ctrl+shift+v on Windows).  Press Q for the transform tool, and rotate the copy while holding shift to get 45 degree increments.

[image]

Repeat.

[image]

The alternate method, which is also helpful for rotating multiple symbols at once, is to change the reference point of the transform tool.  It's the little white dot at the center of the bounding box:

[image]

Move it to the center of the circle and rotate, and you have the same effect.

[image]

Edit: in this example, moving the reference point snaps it into place at the center of the circle, because the origin of all of the symbols meet there.  You can also get a mathematically precise snap by drawing an X or + and aligning it with the center of the circle (solely for the purposes of having something to snap to), then delete it when you're done.

Comment: That's it. Great !!. yes this is exactly what I was looking for.